# Problems with AFNetwork.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, ipad

I'm having problems with AFNetworking.
My webservice is expecting to two parameters of the type NSString to return YES or NO.
My code is this

> AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]
>   initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@" http://webservice.com"]];
>
> ```
> NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
>                                                         path:path
>                                                   parameters:@{
>                                 @"password":@"password",
>                                 @"username":@"username"}
>
>
>                                 ];
>
> AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
>
> operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
>
> [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)  {
>
>     NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
>
>
> }
>                                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
>                                       NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
>
>                                   }
>  ];
>
> NSLog(@"%@", operation.request);
>
> [operation start];
> ```

It does not write:

`NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString)`; ou

> NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);

That is, will not enter the blcok.

Any suggestion?

Greetings

Comment: Don't set the outputStream for the operation and check again.

Comment: 1) verify your web service using a rest client so you know it *should* work.  2) Looks like you're outputting to the same path variable your passing into the request, which may or may not be an issue (and probably not related to your main issue), but you might want to verify that piece of code works as you expect as well.  You might want to look at constructing the destination path using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.  The actual code of doing the request and executing the completion blocks looks good.